# Pascal - Assignment to Function Call

Tags: delphi, syntax, pascal

I am looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bravesoftdz/cbuilder-vcl) for CodeGear C++ Builder header files. In `Source/vcl/forms.pas` I find the following lines of code:

```
procedure TApplication.CreateForm(InstanceClass: TComponentClass; var Reference);
var
  Instance: TComponent;
begin
  Instance := TComponent(InstanceClass.NewInstance); // 메타클래스 이용하여, 인스턴스화
  TComponent(Reference) := Instance;
  try
    Instance.Create(Self); // 폼 생성
  except
    TComponent(Reference) := nil;
    raise;
  end;
  if (FMainForm = nil) and (Instance is TForm) then
  begin
    TForm(Instance).HandleNeeded; // 윈도우핸들을 생성
    FMainForm := TForm(Instance);
  end;
end;
```

Contextually, what I think is happening is that this procedure creates an instance of type `InstanceClass` and returns that instance through `Reference`. In my call, `InstanceClass` is not `TForm`, so the second half doesn't matter.

I am confused by `TComponent(Reference) := Instance;`. **Syntactically, what is happening here?** Is this assignment by reference? Is this assigning a new `TComponent` with the instantiator argument `Reference` being assigned the value? Is `TComponent()` a type casting?

Comment: This just tells the compiler to treat the untyped var param as though was of type TComponent

Comment: Isnt it a violation of Borland's/Embarcadero's licensing to post the entire VCL source code on an open source website?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: GitHub responds to DMCA complaints, but it seems like [the original repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20151231183612/https://code.google.com/p/cbuilder-vcl/) was GNU GPL’d.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt "*the original repository was GNU GPL’d*" - not by Borland, it wasn't. They NEVER open-sourced their proprietary code. They provide their framework source code with the IDE for reference purposes only, but not for open distribution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, then your answer post is in violation of copyright, too. You cannot translate a foreign work without the author’s permission. Kindly inform Borland Inc. [i. e. Micro Focus now] of your, Groger’s, and the GH repository’s violations yourself, so they can file DMCA complaints if they think it’s warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the `procedure`’s signature the formal parameter `reference` does not indicate a data type, but is declared as a `var`iable parameter.
2. Typeless parameters are not legal in Pascal, but permitted in dialects such as [GNU Pascal](https://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Subroutine-Parameter-List-Declaration.html) and FreePascal.
   There, such [variable parameters](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/150948) accept actual parameters of *any* data type.
   The compiler will not enforce/restrict permissible data types, but it must be *addressable* (i. e. literals are not permitted).
3. `dataTypeName(expression)` is indeed a typecast (also illegal in Pascal, but allowed by some dialects).
   Specifically, `dataTypeName(variableName)` is a [variable typecast](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/150947#variable_typecast).
   It will be treated as if `variableName` was of the named data type.
   This is necessary, because in this particular case `reference` has no associated data type.
   No associated data type means, there is no agreed rule in how to access the variable in question (i. e. any read/write access is impossible).
4. The procedure *probably* creates an instance of `TComponentClass`, i. e. the data type of the parameter `InstanceClass`, but there you should really read the documentation of the `NewInstance` method.
   I can only tell you it’s a descendant of `TComponent` otherwise it hardly makes sense to typecast to an unrelated class.

Answer (score 0):

The `Reference` parameter is an untyped `var` parameter. In C++ terms, it is *roughly* equivalent to `void*`, ie the address of any variable can be bound to it.  The code is type-casting the `Reference` to the equivalent of `TComponent*&` or `TComponent**` and then assigning the `Instance` variable (a `TComponent*` pointer) to the caller's passed variable.

The code is *roughly* equivalent to the following in C++ (except that metaclasses and virtual constructors don't exist in C++, so this code is actually not usable in C++):

```cpp
void __fastcall TApplication::CreateForm(TComponentClass* InstanceClass, void* Reference)
{
    // this just allocates a block of memory of the required size...
    TComponent* Instance = static_cast<TComponent*>(InstanceClass->NewInstance());

    // *static_cast<TComponent**>(Reference) = Instance;
    reinterpret_cast<TComponent*&>(Reference) = Instance;

    try
    {
        // This is calling the class' virtual constructor
        // on the allocated memory.  In C++, this would be
        // similar to calling 'placement-new' if the class
        // type was known statically here...

        // new(Instance) InstanceClass->ClassType()(this);
        Instance->Create(this);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // *static_cast<TComponent**>(Reference) = NULL;
        reinterpret_cast<TComponent*&>(Reference) = NULL;
        throw;
    }

    if ((!FMainForm) && (dynamic_cast<TForm*>(Instance) != NULL))
    {
        static_cast<TForm*>(Instance)->HandleNeeded();
        FMainForm = static_cast<TForm*>(Instance);
    }
}
```

```
// Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form1);
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm), reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Form1));
```